# fg a bg process because you forgot to redirect output to /dev/null

Tags: bash, command-line, process, io-redirection, job-control

I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> `bg` with the intention of disowning next, but I forgot to redirect, now I cant get to my terminal because the scrolling of the output (tarballed a huge directory with verbose set).

How do I get a prompt when `STDOUT` from `tar` is filling the screen and I already sent it to the background?

I am using Bash 4.

Comment: This happens to me all the time with rsync or du

Answer (score 4):

You actually have a prompt already, you just can't see it because it's scrolled off screen.

The simplest thing to type is probably <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> (to kill any partial line you've typed at the prompt), `fg`, <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> which will bring it back to the foreground then suspend it again. Simple is nice in this case as you're doing it blindly.

It may take a few seconds to work, as your terminal is struggling to keep up with the output.

You can see clearly what this does by using a command that spews to the terminal slowly (note that my PS1 includes $? when non-zero):

```
anthony@Zia:~$ perl -E 'say "ha" while sleep(1)'
ha
ha
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 perl -E 'say "ha" while sleep(1)'
anthony@Zia:~ [$?=148]$ bg %1
[1]+ perl -E 'say "ha" while sleep(1)' &
ha
anthony@Zia:~$ ha
ha
ha
ha
ha
^C
anthony@Zia:~ [$?=130]$ ha
fha
g
perl -E 'say "ha" while sleep(1)'
ha
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 perl -E 'say "ha" while sleep(1)'
anthony@Zia:~ [$?=148]$
```

At this point, you have it stopped again, and can do whatever you'd like with it.

Comment: Use `Ctrl-U` to kill whatever you've typed so far.

Comment: @glennjackman Ctrl-U won't work if you happen to have managed to hit the left arrow key when typing blidly (or control-A, or any other way of not being on the last character). You could do control-E, control-U or control-U, control-K, but that's more keystrokes.